# React-Native: TextInput cursor always at end instead of touch location

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

I have a basic TextInput with some initial value set to it. 
The problem I am facing is as the user clicks on the TextInput for the first time, the cursor always moves to the end of the text, instead of to the position where the user clicked.
But on the second click the TextInput selection is setting the cursor at the right location. Even after the focus is removed.

Here is the snack for the above scenario.

https://snack.expo.io/@ahetawal/android-textinput-cursor

1. When you first launch the snack, and click anywhere on the textInput you will see the cursor always moves to the end of the text.
2. Try clicking the button to remove the focus and dismiss the keyboard.
3. Click on the any word again, the cursor this time is rightly set at the position expected.

Comment: It's been 4 year, If you solve this, please give me a solution, i'm stuck now